# Windows Automated Installation Kit (WAIK) with a raw Windows 2008R2 ISO

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, automated-install, provisioning, waik

I am new to [WAIK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349343%28WS.10%29.aspx), and am trying to figure out how to build a WIM image from the Windows 2008 R2 ISO media.

So far I have been unsuccessful in finding this information.

Is this possible, and if so, what am I missing from the TechNet documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WAIK documentation has a step by step document of how to image a system.  By default this is at `C:\Program Files\Windows AIK\Docs\Whitepapers\stepbystep_itpro.htm`

depending on what you are trying to deploy i would encourage you to also look at the microsoft deployment toolkit, which automates much of the WAIK.

the command to capture an image from the reference install is `imagex.exe /capture d: d:\myimage.wim "my server install" /compress fast /verify`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to build a WIM image, it's included in the install media. It's located at \sources\install.wim. That's what you manipulate with DISM/MDT.